# What sorting algorithm does List.sort() using to sort the list of custom type?

Tags: list

i am wondering what sorting algorithm does List.sort() is based upon. When i try to sort the following order and have written a debug statement inside the compareTo method it gives the following output. But the final list is a sorted one from 1,2,3,4,5. Any thoughts please.

**Original List**

```
    jobs.add(new OpenSalesOrderWrapper(5,'E','T'));
    jobs.add(new OpenSalesOrderWrapper(2,'B','Q'));
    jobs.add(new OpenSalesOrderWrapper(1,'A','P'));
    jobs.add(new OpenSalesOrderWrapper(4,'D','S'));
    jobs.add(new OpenSalesOrderWrapper(3,'C','R'));
```

**From debug log:**

```
07:57:10.049 (49903000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|5
07:57:10.049 (49960000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|5
07:57:10.049 (49999000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|2
07:57:10.050 (50035000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|5
07:57:10.050 (50072000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|2
07:57:10.050 (50107000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|5
07:57:10.050 (50142000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|4
07:57:10.050 (50177000)|USER_DEBUG|[24]|DEBUG|2
```

Comment: `Comparable` is just an interface. It defines a contract, not the actual functionality (implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the question is really what algorithm does [List.sort](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_sort) use (that in turn influences how often the `Comparable.compareTo` method is called)?

I don't think this is documented but someone with inside knowledge may choose to comment. A reasonable candidate would be Java's [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) that has this to say in its documentation:

> The sorting algorithm is a modified mergesort (in which the merge is
>   omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the
>   lowest element in the high sublist). This algorithm offers guaranteed
>   n log(n) performance. The specified list must be modifiable, but need
>   not be resizable. This implementation dumps the specified list into an
>   array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each
>   element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the
>   n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a
>   linked list in place.

Comment: List.sort() used quick sort however non-primitive object like wrapper using Comparable interface uses merge sort.